# BMI calculator NaN output

Tags: java

I've just recently started coding in Java, using Notepad as requested by my professor, and am required to create a BMI calculator (which I've done before in C++). However, though both my class and driver compile -and I don't see any errors-, the program output returns 'NaN' when it should return a float. Could anyone let me know where I went wrong? The code for the class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BMICalculator
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    float weight;
    float height;
    float bmi;
    public float calculateBMI()
    {
        bmi = (weight / (height * height)) * 703;
    }
    public void setWeight(float aWeight)
    {
        weight = aWeight;
    }
    public void setHeight(float aHeight)
    {
        height = aHeight;
    }
    public float getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }
    public float getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    public float getBMI()
    {
        return bmi;
    }
    public void ask()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a weight in pounds: ");
        weight = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Enter a height in inches: ");
        height = input.nextFloat();
        calculateBMI();
    }
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Body Mass Index: " + bmi);
        if (bmi <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 1.0 && bmi < 18.5)
        {
            System.out.println("Underweight.");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25.0)
        {
            System.out.println("Normal weight.");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 25.0 && bmi < 30.0)
        {
            System.out.println("Overweight.");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 30.0)
        {
            System.out.println("Obese.");
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the driver main:

```
public class BMICalculatorDriver
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        BMICalculator userBMI = new BMICalculator();
        userBMI.ask();
        userBMI.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine to me, why you are writing setters if you are setting the variable with a class method only? Also added return type as float for `calculateBMI` function, but you are not returning anything. Can you add the main method also? So we can identify the exact root cause for your issue.

Comment: Code works just fine, just tested. As @Sandeep Kokate said your calculateBMI returns a float but all you do is assign the bmi variable. Change the function to return void.

Comment: You didn't show us how you run the code (main). Please post the complete code!

Comment: If you are using notepad++ and running java program with command prompt, then `javac BMICalculatorDriver.java` should give you the compile-time error, due to missing return statement for `calculateBMI` function, change the return type to void as you are not returning anything from that function or simply return `bmi`

Comment: Got the program to work! I changed the return type for the calculateBMI function to void and tested it on Eclipse. Thanks y'all!